# Using indexOf on an array inside .map()

Tags: javascript

I am starting with an array and want to see if the key already exists in the array.

```
keys = ['pitch1']

var y = [
  {header: 'pitch1', data: 'pitch1 data'}, 
  {header: 'pitch3', data: 'pitch3 data'}, 
  {header: 'pitch4', data: 'pitch4 data'},
  {header: 'pitch2', data: 'pitch2 data'},
  {header: 'pitch1', data: 'more pitch 1 data'},
]


y.map((item, index) => {
  if (keys.indexOf[item.header]) {
    console.log('found it')
  } else {
    console.log('not found')
  }
})
```

This is returning:

```
"not found"
"not found"
"not found"
"not found"
"not found"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ps who is downvoting this and why?

Comment: a) you have to call `indexOf`, not access a property on it b) it would return `0` (if found in first place) or `-1` (if not found) which doesn't match the log statements in the respective case

Comment: I think you're looking for `if (keys.includes(item.header))`

Comment: yup! that was causing an issue :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keys.indexOf[item.header]` should be `keys.indexOf(item.header)` and change your if condition to `if (keys.indexOf(item.header) != -1)` `indexOf` returns `-1` when it can't find the object

The reason it returns `-1` instead of `false` is that a needle at the beginning of the string would be at position `0`, which is equivalent to `false` in Javascript. So returning `-1` ensures that you know there is not actually a match.

```js
keys = ['pitch1']

var y = [
  {header: 'pitch1', data: 'pitch1 data'}, 
  {header: 'pitch3', data: 'pitch3 data'}, 
  {header: 'pitch4', data: 'pitch4 data'},
  {header: 'pitch2', data: 'pitch2 data'},
  {header: 'pitch1', data: 'more pitch 1 data'},
]


y.map((item, index) => {
  if (keys.indexOf(item.header) != -1) {
    console.log('found it')
  } else {
    console.log('not found')
  }
})
```

Comment: thank you! will accept this when I can.

Comment: `when I can` means?

Comment: won't let me accept for 6 more minutes

Comment: @MorganAllen Ok :)

Comment: @MorganAllen: I'd change `.map()` to `.forEach()`, since `.map()` was an odd choice there. With `.map()`, you're creating a new array and then ignoring it. You can also remove the `index` parameter from the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Your `indexOf` function is returning `0`.

`0` is a falsey value in Javascript. Change your condition as follows:

```
if (keys.indexOf(item.header) >= 0)
```

Comment: @Ryad `> -1` not `>= -1` at best

Comment: @Ryad Why would `>= -1` be better? `-1` is not found.

Comment: @timothyclifford: If it's not there, it won't give a match when the index is `0`.

Comment: `.includes()` is nicer than `.indexOf()`.

Comment: @rockstar `includes` isn't supported in IE + in many cases `indexOf` is faster

Comment: .includes isn't supported in ES6/ES2015 (or so I've read)

Comment: @Dieterg: They perform essentially the same operation. If `.includes()` is slower, it's only because it has not yet been optimized, but certainly will be.

Comment: @MorganAllen: Does that matter? It's from the ES2016 standard.

Comment: I actually don't know :-) I just read that elsewhere as a reason not to use it.

Comment: @MorganAllen: Oh, yeah people say lots of strange stuff online. Its standard is only a year newer and there are polyfills available in abundance for the newer stuff. Lots of older browsers also don't support arrow functions, and those require an actual transpiler to use in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for this purpose like:

```js
keys = ['pitch1']

var y = [
  {header: 'pitch1', data: 'pitch1 data'}, 
  {header: 'pitch3', data: 'pitch3 data'}, 
  {header: 'pitch4', data: 'pitch4 data'},
  {header: 'pitch2', data: 'pitch2 data'},
  {header: 'pitch1', data: 'more pitch 1 data'},
]

var found = y.some(v => keys.includes(v.header));
if (found) {
    console.log('found it')
} else {
    console.log('not found')
}
```

Comment: Yeah, if they want a single `console.log()` instead of one for each match, then `.some()` is much nicer. If they do want multiple logs, `.map()` was still a strange choice instead of `.forEach()`